# Azure Active Directory B2C and Android Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c

We are currently integrating Azure Active Directory B2C with an Android native mobile app. The problem we have now encountered is that the authentication flow we are implementing requires opening a third party authentication app (Swedish BankId), this means that the Android app will end up in the background and will not redirect the user back to Azure Active Directory B2C, and the login flow is stopped. Does anyone have a solution to the problem of and Android in the background with web pages in Chrome Custom Tabs?

Similar issues are explained here: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/135

Comment: try using onActivityResult(). Check the documentation on the link below. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: It seems like this event also isn't invoked when the app is in background state and the authenticator app is active.

Comment: thanks for adding that reference to github. Does it happen when you call another browser app, such as firefox or opera for android devices?

Comment: It works with Firefox.

Comment: please, find below this interesting article about managing authentication with CCT. Have you already overridden onNewIntent() method in your activity class? https://medium.com/@ajinkyabadve/do-authentication-in-android-using-custom-chrome-tab-cct-2a0edffc93fd

Comment: This is now solved by using another web view component. Chrome Custom Tabs is an issue on Android when the app is running in the background.